# Vue.js not updating v-modal value in window until method ends

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a method which has a loop inside and it calls an ajax post request and appends the received value to v-modal bound variable. But the value does not updated in the view until the whole loop and method is completed running. I want it to update the value in the view as soon as the value is updated with a new value.

Am I doing this wrong way. Please suggest a method to fix this.

**HTML**

```
<button v-on:click="getResult">Process</button>
<textarea id="result-section" v-model="result"></textarea>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    delimiters: ["<%", "%>"],
    data: {
    result: '',
    dataJson: {...},
    cmdOutput,
},
methods: {
    getData: function (neName, cmd) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getdata/cmd/',
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'cmdData': [{ 'neName': neName, 'cmd': cmd }],
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    if (data["status"] == "3") {
                        app.cmdOutput = data['Result'];
                    } else {
                        app.cmdOutput = '';
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                app.cmdOutput = '';
            },
            timeout: 7000
        });
    },
    getResult: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < app.dataJson.length; i++) {
          getData(app.dataJson[i]["neName"],app.dataJson[i]["cmd"]);
          app.result+=cmdOutput+"\n";
        }
    },
    }
})
```

Please help. Thanks!